# parsing recursive XML with SAX

Tags: android, xml, parsing, sax

The last couple days I tried to parse a XML file but I got no success. Im using SAX parser but the XML is recursive and I don't know you to control de parsing.

The XML is quite extense, but below you can see a sample of how it is.

```
<root>
  <prop1>teste</prop1>
  <items>
     <item>
        <prop1>teste1</prop1>
        <items>         
          <item>
             <prop1>teste1.1</prop1>
             <items null />
          </item>
        </items>
     </item>
     <item>
       <prop1>teste1</prop1>
       <items null />
     </item>
  </items>
</root>
```

I don't know how to handle the loop inside the startElement and the endElement methods.
Any help would be cool... thanks in advance.

Comment: You should link to your XML. Noone will do your parsing for you and you can't use the code if we try by your "sample".

Comment: Basically, you need to keep track of where you are in the tree, which is most often done with a stack. Exactly how is dependent on what you want to do with the XML. Tell us that and you will get better answers.

Comment: SAX parsing is low-level and difficult. It might not be the right approach for you. We can't really help you understand the computer science of parsing theory. We can't help you design your application unless you tell us what it's supposed to do. If your code doesn't work we can tell you where you went wrong, but only if you show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2000/jw-0804-sax.html?page=1

This article shows how to employ the SAX API to map XML documents to Java objects.

Hope this helps you.
Let me know if you have more doubts.

Thanks.